# Is it possible to divide an xml property file to subsections?

Tags: java

With Properties.loadFromXml method I can retrieve an xml property file.
Is it possible to divide this file in subsections like, for example:

```
<properties>
  <entry key="normalprop">normal value</entry>
  <aSubsection key="subname">
       <entry key="suboption">suboption value</entry>
       <entry key="suboption">suboption value</entry>
  </aSubsection>

<properties>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the Java 7 Javadoc :

> The XML document must have the following DOCTYPE declaration:
>
> `<!DOCTYPE properties SYSTEM "http://java.sun.com/dtd/properties.dtd">`

The DOCTYPE definition is used by the `Properties` API to check the format of the file and throw an exception if it doesn't fit. If you read it, you'll see that it only allows `<entry>` and `<comment>` elements inside the `<properties>` segment.

You'll have to write your own code for handling sections, or you can use the [Commons Configuration](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-configuration/) library which allows for hierarchical properties.

Answer (score 1):

I think there are two alternatives for you:

1. Write a custom property like *inlcude*. If you find any properties like this, read the additional property files before-after you parsed the current one.
2. Use an alternative, like [Apache Commons Configuration](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-configuration/) which supports *include-and-override*-like configuration.